# Azure FileShare and blob container alternative

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-files

I'm new to Azure WebApps and storage, what I'm trying to understand is how best to mount storage on Azure WebApp (Linux OS) with read/write capabilities.

I am deploying a CMS application which allows site administrator to add content including uploading files (images, docs, videos, pdfs etc...). These need to be stored on a file server and cannot be stored in the webroot, hence why I need to mount blob container allowing hierarchical namespace (i.e. a folder structure). The CMS application then renders these files to a webpage. Think of it as Wordpress.

The issue I'm facing is, file share does not allow anonymous access and requires SAS URL, Data Lake Gen 2 (ADLS 2) is read only but does allows access anonymously. Is there an alternative way to mount storage to a WebApp with the ability to read anonymously and has write permissions?

**The problem with using File Share**

Anonymous access is not allowed for files stored in file storage, the access needs to be authorised. One way of authorising the access is to create a SAS on a file/share level with Read permission and then using that SAS URL to access the file. This is not possible in my scenario.

**Problem with  Data Lake Gen 2 storage**

Mounted Blob containers are read only
"Mounted Blob containers will become read only in Feb 2020" and [MS recommend to use azure files!](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/BringYourOwnStorage/mounting_azure_blob.md)

Comment: Can't you use Storage SDK and upload the files in blob container?

Comment: I don't know what that is how is that different from Gen 2 (ADLS 2) ? I'll look into it. thank you

Comment: You can use Storage SDK to upload files in ADLS Gen 2 accounts.

Comment: I've done some research on the SDK and that would required rewriting parts of the CMS for performing CRUD operation on the objects and that is not possible as its a massive piece of software to change. My question, Is there a way to mount storage to a WebApp with the ability to read anonymously and has write permissions?